# Изменение стилей элемента через setInterval на Vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, setinterval

Хочу понять, как работает Vue: читал документацию, много гуглил, но не могу понять, как мне нужно написать функцию, чтобы получить желаемый результат.

Есть четыре блока, в которых есть тег `h3`. Мне нужно каждые несколько секунд убирать стиль у одного элемента, и добавлять этот стиль к следующему. Всего их четыре. Идея была такая: сделать массив из идентификаторов, а потом с помощью `setInterval` переключаться между ними. Но поле `el`, как я понял, менять нельзя.

Моя попытка:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 p-0 text-center d-inline-block " id="service_webdesign">
  <img src="css/img/pencil.png" class="p-30" alt="Web & App Design">
  <h3 v-bind:class="{service__title__active: isActive}" class="service__title p-30 m-0" id="service__title__1">Web & App Design</h3>
  <p class="service__description p-30 m-0" id="service__title__1">Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim.</p>
  <hr class="service_scroll">
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#service__title__1',
  data: {
    isActive: false,
    id: ['#service__title__1', '#service__title__2', '#service__title__3', '#service__title__4'],
  },

  methods: {
    titleChanger: function() {
      var a = this;
      var n = 0;
      var element = document.getElementById(a.id[n]);
      setInterval(function() {
        a.el = element;
        a.isActive = true;
        n++;
        if (n > 3) {
          n = 0;
        }
        element = document.getElementById(a.id[n]);

      }, 1000)
    }

  },
  mounted() {
    this.titleChanger();
  }

})
```

---

Как правильно воплотить эту задумку в реальность?

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/981592/256824

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для выполнения этой задачи подойдет следующая схема:

- создать индекс активной услуги;
- с помощью метода `setInterval` менять этот индекс;
- добавить вычисляемое свойство стиля, которое будет зависеть от этого индекса.

Ниже демонстрация данного подхода.

```js
// Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    // Индекс текущей активной услуги.
    currentIndex: 0,

    // Модель нашего таймера.
    timing: null,

    // Модель с услугами (массив услуг).
    services: [{
      title: 'Voluptatem enim optio',
      description: 'Maiores adipisci et ut ipsam quo voluptas. Nulla atque et cupiditate odit.',
      image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/180x80'
    }, {
      title: 'Eum praesentium autem',
      description: 'Sint sapiente error eum. Et eveniet omnis deserunt sunt.',
      image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/180x80'
    }, {
      title: 'Voluptatem nihil voluptate',
      description: 'Odit consequatur accusantium excepturi minima velit. Et molestiae maiores ea.',
      image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/180x80'
    }, {
      title: 'Debitis illum ex eum',
      description: 'Commodi quia asperiores dignissimos sint quo tempore. Neque magni aut.',
      image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/180x80'
    }]
  },

  computed: {
    /**
     * Вычисляемое свойство:
     * указывает является ли переданный index
     * равнозначным индексу текущей активной услуги.
     */
    isActive() {
      return index => this.currentIndex === index
    },

    // Задаем стили (класс) для активной услуги.
    activeStyle() {
      return index => {
        return {
          'service__title-active': this.isActive(index)
        }
      }
    }
  },

  /**
   * Используем хук `mounted` для запуска таймера.
   */
  mounted() {
    this.runTiming()
  },

  methods: {
    // Запускаем наш таймер.
    runTiming() {
      this.timing = setInterval(this.changeCurrentIndex, 1000)
    },

    // Изменяем индекс текущей активной услуги.
    changeCurrentIndex() {
      // services.length - количество услуг.
      // ++ - увеличиваем активную услугу на единицу.
      // a % b – это остаток от деления a на b.
      this.currentIndex = ++this.currentIndex % this.services.length;
    }
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    // При использовании компонентного подхода
    // обязательно удаляем наш таймер.
    clearInterval(this.timing)
  }
});
```

```css
.services {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.service {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.service__title-active {
  color: #08c;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  {{ currentIndex }}
  <div class="services">
    <template v-for="(service, index) in services">
      <article class="service">
        <h3 :class="activeStyle(index)">{{ service.title }}</h3>
        <img :src="service.image" :alt="service.title">
        <p>{{ service.description }}</p>
      </article>
    </template>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/1ngch2oL/)

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
                <h3 :class="isActive(1)" ref="service__title__1">Web & App Design</h3>
                <h3 :class="isActive(2)" ref="service__title__1">Web & App Design</h3>
                <h3 :class="isActive(3)" ref="service__title__1">Web & App Design</h3>
                <h3 :class="isActive(4)" ref="service__title__1">Web & App Design</h3>



            </div>
</div>

.active {
  background-color:red;
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   currentIndex: 1,
   elementsCount:4
  },
  mounted(){
  let self = this;
  setInterval(function(){
  self.nextEl();
  },2000)
  },
  methods:{
  isActive(val){
  return this.currentIndex === val ?  "active" :'' ;
  },
  nextEl(){
  console.log(this.currentIndex);
  this.currentIndex = this.currentIndex === this.elementsCount ? 1 : ++this.currentIndex;
  }
  }
})
```

Можно доработать под Ваш функционал.

"#el" менять нельзя, потому что это указатель на элемент который надо отрендерить как экземпляр Vue

Comment: Спасибо большое! По примерам Vue смотрел, даже не додумался, что можно isActive как метод сделать. Учиться и учиться еще