# Добавление css классов по условию в Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

При переносе кода из проекта на asp.net core в бекенд на vue я столкнулся с тем, что хочу записать некоторые фрагменты шаблона более лаконично.

Вот исходный фрагмент:

```
<li class="page-item disabled" v-if="isFirst">
    <a class="page-link" :href="firstUrl">&#171;&#171;</a>
</li>
<li class="page-item" v-if="!isFirst">
    <a class="page-link" :href="firstUrl">&#171;&#171;</a>
</li>
```

Однако в php у меня была бы возможность написать это ещё короче, примерно вот в таком виде (неработающий код, просто концепт):

```
<li class="page-item {{ isFirst ? 'disabled' : '' }}">
    <a class="page-link" :href="firstUrl">&#171;&#171;</a>
</li>
```

Можно ли как-то это сделать в vue.js?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43210508

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такая штука вообще есть, только делается не так в лоб. Подсмотрел пример вот в этом вопросе на en so: [Vue.js: Conditional class styling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43210508/5752652)

В моём примере получается будет вот так:

```
  <li :class="{ 'disabled': isFirst(), 'page-item': true }">
    <a class="page-link" :href="firstUrl">&#171;</a>
  </li>
```

И оказывается  и [в документации есть про это](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html), просто нужно было вспомнить, что это можно было применить к текущему вопросу.

Альтернативная версия, предложенная @Дмытрык:

```
  <li :class="[{ 'disabled': isFirst()}, 'page-item']">
    <a class="page-link" :href="firstUrl">&#171;</a>
  </li>
```

Comment: результат тот же, но как мне кажется, лаконичнее/правильнее такая запись `<li :class="['page-item', { 'disabled': isFirst()}]">`

Comment: @Дмытрык Спасибо. Дополнил ответ, чтобы каждый мог выбрать вариант, который ему больше нравится.

Comment: @РустамГимранов А, это перевод. Я всегда забываю в них зайти через два дня и поставить галку. Спасибо за напоминание.

Answer (score 3):

Если вывод класса нужен по условию `v-if`, а количество классов и условий разрастается и всё это выводится через цикл `v-for`, то нужно это дело выносить в поле `computed` и визуально не перегружать шаблон. Если есть класс, который постоянно должен быть закреплен за элементом, то используется обычный `html` атрибут `class="some-class"`.

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <div class="const-class" :class="bestCompanyClass(item.id)">
    <!--  -->
  </div>
</div>
```

```
data: {
  bestCompany: 3,
  items: []
},

computed: {
  bestCompanyClass() {
      return (id) => {
        return {
          'best-company': this.bestCompany === id,
          'другой-класс': условие вывода класса,
          'третий-класс': условие вывода класса,
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Если никаких данных в вычисляемый класс не передаётся, то:

```
computed: {
  validatedClass() {
    return {
      'is-valid': this.wasValidated,
      'другой-класс': условие вывода класса,
      'третий-класс': условие вывода класса,
    }
  }
}
```