# Применение стилей к классам из запроса

Tags: javascript, css3, vue.js

Проект написан на Vue.js.
Есть некоторый запрос, в котором к нам приходят данные для стилей например `bg_color: '000000'` , сделано это для того ,что бы админ мог менять на любые цвета. Из запроса достать данный не проблема, а вот добавить к классу..
Подскажите как подставить в класс,полученные данные из запроса, `000000` в `background_color: #...`

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/981592/213987

Comment: @AK, Дубликат? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В [документации](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-inline-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9) имеются исчерпывающие примеры:

```html
<div v-bind:style="{ color: activeColor, fontSize: fontSize + 'px' }"></div>
```

```js
// ...
data: function() {
    return {
        activeColor: 'red',
        fontSize: 30
    }
},
methods: {
    setActiveColor: function(color){
        this.activeColor = color;
    }
},
// ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот примерно так. Переменные resp1 и resp2 имитируют данные, которые прилетают от сервера. [Тут](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles) можно подробнее почитать что к чему.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    text: 'someText',
    resp1: '000000',
    resp2: '00ff00',
    current: '',
  },
  methods: {
    use1() {
      this.current = '#' + this.resp1;
      console.log(this.current);
    },
    use2() {
      this.current = '#' + this.resp2;
      console.log(this.current);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.main {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="main" :style="{'background-color': current}">
  <button @click="use1">resp1</button>
  <button @click="use2">resp2</button>
  {{ text }}
</div>
```