# Переключение классов при изменение входящих данных во vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Вопрос**: есть класс который стилизует данные, когда данные не приходят в полях прописываю "нет данных"... как привязать класс к span'у при отсутствие данных?

**Код**:

```
   <span class="inputData">{{ returnFormattedValue(inputDataType, parameterValue) }}</span>

         /**
         * Метод который для определенных полей подставляет либо "%" либо "дн",
         * если данные не получены выводится "нет данных"
         */
   returnFormattedValue(inputDataType, parameterValue) {
         if (parameterValue) {
                if (inputDataType === 'breathalyzer' || inputDataType === 'examiner') {
                    return parameterValue + ' %';
                } else if (inputDataType !== "userMedicalReplacement") {
                    return parameterValue + ' дн';
                }
         } else {
             return 'нет данных';
         }
  }
```

**p.s:** все примеры с v-bind нашел только по клику, а с двумя span'ами через v-if выглядит как мне кажется костыльно(но я могу ошибаться)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/981592/256824

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Для динамической установки или удаления CSS-классов можно передавать объект в директиву v-bind:class:

```
<div v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }"></div>
```

> Запись выше означает, что наличие класса active будет определяться истинностью параметра isActive.

[Документация](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

В вашем случае

```
<span class="inputData" :class="{'some-class': !parameterValue}">{{ returnFormattedValue(inputDataType, parameterValue) }}</span>
```

Comment: Спасибо) Вариант с v-bind тоже хорош...

Answer (score 2):

Используйте реактивность `vue`, сделайте переменную например dynamic_class

```
<span :class="dynamic_class">{{ returnFormattedValue(inputDataType, parameterValue) }}</span>

         /**
         * Метод который для определенных полей подставляет либо "%" либо "дн",
         * если данные не получены выводится "нет данных"
         */
   returnFormattedValue(inputDataType, parameterValue) {
         if (parameterValue) {
                if (inputDataType === 'breathalyzer' || inputDataType === 'examiner') {
                    return parameterValue + ' %';
                } else if (inputDataType !== "userMedicalReplacement") {
                    return parameterValue + ' дн';
                }
                this.dynamic_class = 'inputClass';
         } else {
             this.dynamic_class = 'anotherInputClass';
             return 'нет данных';
         }
  }
```

Только не забудьте в `data` добавить переменную. Ну и соответственно в тегах `<style>` у вас должны быть описаны классы `.inputClass` и `.anotherInputClass`

Comment: Спасибо ,буду внедрять) (все просто оказалось)